# Get post_type by term_id

Tags: custom-post-types

Is it possible to find out which post_type a term_id belongs to?

I have this bit of code to try and collect all possible categories into an array, but I would like to add the post type each category belongs to into the array.

```
$post_catgegories_objects = get_categories(
    array(
        'type'       => 'post',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'hide_empty' => '0',
    )
);

foreach ( $post_catgegories_objects as $cat ) {
    $post_catgegories[] = array(
        $cat->term_id,
        $cat->name,
        $cat->slug,
    );
}

// var_dump($post_type);
// exit;

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies(
    array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false,
    )
);

foreach ( $taxonomies as $key => $taxonomy ) {
    if ( stristr( $taxonomy, 'cat' ) ) {
        $tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

        // print_r($tax_terms);
        // exit;

        foreach ( $tax_terms as $term ) {
            $cpt_categegories[] = array(
                $term->term_id,
                $term->name,
                $term->slug,
            );
        }
    }
}

$all_categories = array_merge( $post_catgegories, $cpt_categegories );

print_r( $all_categories );
exit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the post type that a term's taxonomy is attached to, if that's what you mean.

```
$post_type = get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->object_type[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `post_type` by `term_id`

```
$args = array('hide_empty' => 0,'orderby' => 'name');
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
    $term = get_term_by('id', $value->term_id , 'activity_category');
    $post_type = get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy )->object_type[0];
}
```